# Mathematical induction: $f_{2n+1}=f^2_{n+1}+f^2_n$

Tags: induction

**What did I do wrong in the proof by mathematical induction of $f_{2n+1}=f^2_{n+1}+f^2_n$?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, but in that example they proof by n=k, and i want to prove it by n=k+1

Comment: When $n=k+1$, you get $f_{2k+3}$, not $f_{2k+2}$.

Comment: @user8734617 Yes, correct!

Comment: @LeneCoenen Not sure what you mean by that. It's the same identity, and the question has a number of answers posted. See more duplicates [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174633/fibonacci-identity-inductive-proof) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461243/prove-that-f-n2f-n12-f-2n1) for example.

Comment: Dear Lene, why don't you check for duplicates before posting?